# Profiling database intensive code on Linux

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, profiling

I have a set of real time financial trading programs that run on Linux. The code is written in C++ and is very database intensive (MySQL). We've tried to use Memory tables where important. While I always care about latency, at certain times of day just raw throughput is the bottleneck.

How can I properly profile this system? I'd like to be able to see percentage of time spent (a) running my application code, i.e. my app code CPU bound, (b) running in MySQL, or (c) running in OS system calls, such as networking related calls. I'd also like to see, for the database at least, time spent waiting on disk.

I also realize that profiling and optimizing for latency is very different than profiling and optimizing for throughput. To optimize for throughput I imagine a traditional profiler that can measure the above would be appropriate. To optimize for latency, I think just logging microsecond accurate time stamps is sufficient, but still makes it hard to pinpoint where all the time is spent when I see outliers.

Am I thinking about this the right way? What tools are out there that might help me out?

Comment: Are You looking into system-level monitoring (like SysTap/DTrace - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap or sysstat/iostat/SAR - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/)? Or rather into AWR-like reports for MySQL to optimize Your schema/indexes? (http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/presentations/mysql-performance-reporting/) Also - what's Your definition of "raw throughput" - is it the IOPS or the amount of data (column width) transferred within each commit?

Comment: Good indexing in MySQL tables is highly important.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth wild to attempt to examine what the database is doing while processing the queries. For instance, understanding how the query optimizer is executing the query. Sometimes forcing the use of an index, removing an index or rearranging the query can have a huge impact.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-profile.html

Also, it may also be advisable to look at how other RMDBs handle your work load. With out looking at the type of queries or the complexity, it is difficult to say if mysql or PostgreSQL will work better for you. But in any event, taking a scientific approach to measuring the data is step 1.

Like Vlad said, your probably want to look at using stap but it is not for the faint of heart, I would recommend it if you're still seeing performance issues.